# how to change css rules in style using javascript when the style media is print?

Tags: javascript

How do you change the css rule of #div1 in the style type="text/css" media="print" using javascript? I want to change the display to none on the click event of a checkbox/button.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 #div1{
 display:visible;
}
</style

<style type="text/css" media="print">
 #div1{
 display:visible;
}
</style
```

Thank You in advance

Comment: I do not want to hide the div from the screen,i only want to hide it while printing it,basically what im trying to do is give the user the option to print a section while printing a page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new CSS class that is applied to whatever `div` you're trying to hide for a particular printing action, and add a rule to the print style sheet that hides it

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.print-hidden {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Your trigger might look something like:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('div1_trigger').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('div1').className = 'print-hidden';
}
</script>
```

Assuming you have multiple sections, you would also have to handle removing the print-hidden class when another section is triggered.

Also, `display: visible;` is not a valid CSS rule, you probably want `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `window.getComputesStyle` method, it will give the actual style of the element:

```
window.getComputedStyle(div1,null).getPropertyValue("display")
```

See docs for details:
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle)